# Malform XML validation in spring WS

Tags: xml, spring, validation

I have used below code in application context xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ......>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.webservice" />
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <sws:static-wsdl id="Signal"
        location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/Signal.wsdl" />

    <bean id="validatingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/Order.xsd" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="Exception">SERVER,Internal server error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It is blocking request if malformed request come from soapUI. But it works in local. When I am deploying it in server then it is not working. Another thing if I bolck the below mentioned prortion of code, still it works in local.

```
<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/Order.xsd" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Note that I have 3 xsds. Order.xsd refers other two. Please tell me if I have to do any things extra for that.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference XSD used below code:

```
<property name="schemas" >
    <array>
            <value>/SubOrder.xsd</value>
            <value>/OrderTypes.xsd</value>
            <value>/Order.xsd</value>
         </array>
</property>
```

I have used these two jars and my problem has been resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```